# How to run a powershell script or change the session and execute code with different user account?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, user-accounts, user-data

I need to run a script using a domain user account from ec2 userdata which is currently running as system user.

My code:

```
start-Process powershell.exe -Credential  $credential -ArgumentList “Start-Process powershell.exe 
'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.ps1' -Verb runAs”
```

But it is creating a popup which may lead to an error in the execution

Answer (score 0):

Just add the NoNewWindow switch to the end.

```
start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList “Start-Process powershell.exe 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.ps1' -Verb runAs” -NoNewWindow
```